# Is there a Disk imager designed for use on raspbian itself?

Tags: raspbian

I haven't been able to find a post with an answer for this question  despite a while of searching... But,  I just downloaded raspbian Jessie to my Pi using the provided browser... And I want to use the image... But there's a plot twist... I want to know if there is a disk imager I can install onto my Raspberry Pi,  to write the image to a micro SD card instead of using my windows computer. I do understand that it may take a few hundred years as the Pi is slower than a Windows computer,  but that's OK.

Im running the latest distro of RaspiJessi on a RPI2B

Comment: @goldilocks, turds... I just realized my auto correct change the title to image from imager last minute before I pressed the submit button. Darn. I'll change that.

Comment: Yeah that's part of what had me confused and auto correct is a tool of Satan ;)  Do beware that using `dd` is probably way simpler, easier, and more foolproof than anything else.  It just requires a keyboard more than a mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are tools for Linux for working with disk images.

The main one is the command line tool [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29).  It should already be there as part of the basic Linux commands.

If you're looking for something with a GUI, look at [ImageWriter](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/usb-imagewriter/).

Both are mentioned, along with usage examples in the [instructions for creating an SD card for the Pi from a Linux computer](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_Card_using_Linux_.28including_on_a_Raspberry_Pi.21.29).

To install ImageWriter on the Pi, the following should work (but I'm unable to test right now)

```
cd ~
wget https://launchpad.net/usb-imagewriter/trunk/0.1/+download/usb-imagewriter-0.1.99.tar.gz
tar -xvzf usb-imagewriter-0.1.99.tar.gz
cd usb-imagewriter-0.1.99.tar.gz
sudo ./install.sh
```

If the wget command fails, you may need to

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

first.

Oh, and don't worry about it being called "usb-imagewriter" - it works just fine for SD cards too ;)

Comment: that's exactly what I am looking for is a GUI. I am just getting used to the techno terminology. How do I download the GUI provided? Simply type in the Web address to the Internet browser on the RPI,  then press the download button and follow the installation procedure? Or is there a specific sudo apt-get install command I must use in the terminal?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no apt packaged version of ImageWriter for the Pi that I can find, so it's a bit of a manual install from the command line.   Amending my answer with install instructions.

Comment: thank you very much. When I get a chance,  I will report back to you and let you know if the command works.